# Coverpoints in System Verilog

Tags: system-verilog

Is it possible to exclude some coverpoints from a particular group based on a parameter?

```
covergroup NEW (string for_exclusion) @ (clk);
option.per_instance = 1;
option.comment = for_exclusion;

apples: coverpoint (available) { bins hit1 = {1'b1};}
bananas: coverpoint ({not_available, less}) {bins hit1 = {1'b1};}
oranges: coverpoint ({available, less}) {bins hit1 = {1'b1};}
rose: coverpoint ({available, flower}) {bins hit1 = {1'b1};}
```

This is small part of the original file. I want to exclude 'rose' from this covergroup based on parameter *parameter IDENTITY = 2'b00* which I have already passed in the module. Is there a way to do this? 
(Please ignore syntax errors, if any. I am not worried about them at the moment)

I tried using this but it did nt work.

```
covergroup NEW (string for_exclusion) @ (clk);
option.per_instance = 1;
option.comment = for_exclusion;

apples: coverpoint (available) { bins hit1 = {1'b1};}
bananas: coverpoint ({not_available, less}) {bins hit1 = {1'b1};}
oranges: coverpoint ({available, less}) {bins hit1 = {1'b1};}

generate
if (IDENTITY = 2'b01) begin
rose: coverpoint ({available, flower}) {bins hit1 = {1'b1};}
end
endgenerate`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `generate` in the middle of declaring another construct. Can you separate that coverpoint out into another covergroup and not construct/sample it based on the other parameter?

Another choice is to set the weight of the coverpoint to 0 based on the parameter. You can do this in procedural code before or after constructing the covergroup.

```
if (IDENTITY != 2'b01)
  NEW::rose::type_option.weight = 0;
```

or inside the coverpoint

```
rose: coverpoint ({available, flower}) {
  bins hit1 = {1'b1};
  option.weight = (IDENTITY == 2'b01};
}
```

Comment: No i cannot separate such coverpoints, as there are some which are common for both parameters and I want to avoid repetition of code. 


Moreover, accessing the coverpoint from inside the covergroup is not supported in my tool. Do we have any other option?

Comment: I said to put the statement in procedural code, not inside in the covergroup

Comment: yes, it's outside the covergroup. Still same issue. Any alternate way?