# Add ignore_bins To Already Defined Coverpoints

Tags: system-verilog, test-coverage

I am working with already generated `coverpoints` and `covergroups`. I have a way to access all the `coverpoints` in the `covergroup` through an  `` `include `` file, but cannot edit the `coverpoints` directly.

```
covergroup cg_FOO;
  apple: coverpoint Atype_e'(sample.apple.value);
  kiwi: coverpoint Ktype_e'(sample.kiwi.vale);

  `ifdef MY_COV
    `include "cg_FOO.svh"
  `endif
end group: cg_FOO
```

cg_FOO.svh is an example for this `covergroup`, but with another generated `covergroup` I have a separate associated file. I define all sorts of `cross`es and non-generated `coverpoints` in these  `` `include ``d files. However, I also want to specify certain enum values for `coverpoints` `apple` and `kiwi` that may not be valid for `cg_FOO`.

If I was able to change each coverpoint, I would just do the following:

```
apple: coverpoint Atype_e'(sample.value) {
  ignore_bins ignore_FUJI = apple with (FUJI);
}
```

But, including a separate file into each `coverpoint` of each `covergroup` is messy and not feasible.

Everything I have found thus far makes it seem like I need to specify an `ignore_bin` inside a `coverpoint` structure. How could I ignore certain bins of a `coverpoint` from within my cg_FOO.svh file (ie in the `covergroup`, but not changing all the generated `coverpoints`)?

Note, I also have 2 other  `` `include `` files to work with, one outside the `covergroups` but inside the class that contains them (I am using this file for macro, variable, and function definitions), and another file to define helping logic just before the `covergroup`s get sampled (ie when `sample` gets defined).

Comment: Do the include files already contain bins, or is it just the `coverpoint` with automatic bins?

Comment: Hi Dave, the cg_<covergroup_name>.svh included files contain crosses of the covergroup's coverpoints (I explicitly write ignore_bins here) as well as a couple coverpoints of their own. The coverpionts in that file automatically generate bins, I don't explicitly write them.
EX: `overlap_apple_kiwi: coverpoint {overlap[0]}`
Note `overlap` is defined in the other `` `include` files and is set by a function call also defined in the other `` `include` file. Seems my simulator will not let me defined logic or function calls in a `covergroup` or `coverpoint` so I use those `` `include` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're out of luck unless the tool you are using gives you an API to access and modify the coverage database. Bins are very difficult to access because they have no easy names to reference them, you have to scan through them. It's very easy to exclude coverpoints externally by setting their weights to 0.

Without knowing exactly what your coverage model looks like, it's hard to give you a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt feedback Dave. I saw this earlier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53612383/coverpoints-in-system-verilog, and noted they excluded covergroups based with weights as well. However, I would like to exclude bins (certain invalid enums). So is that other StackOverflow question what you were referring too and I'm just out of luck, or did you have something else in mind with weights?